# Error in Django when I use createsuperuser command

Tags: python, django

When I use the command createsuperuser in Django, I got an error and I can execute this command, this is my traceback. Also, my Visual Studio Code give me warnings in the imports with the app "miapp".

Thank you, very much.

## Traceback

```
PS C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango> python manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\AprendiendoDjango\urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    from miapp.views import hola_mundo
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\miapp\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import FormArticle
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\miapp\forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    class FormArticle(forms.Form):
  File "C:\xampp1\htdocs\Proyecto Python\AprendiendoDjango\miapp\forms.py", line 19, in FormArticle
    content = forms.CharField(
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 216, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validator'
```

### These are my imports of urls.py

```
from miapp.views import hola_mundo
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

# Importar app con mis vistas
from miapp import views
```

### These are my imports of views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
from .models import Article, Category
from django.db.models import Q
from .forms import FormArticle
from django.contrib  import messages
```

Comment: Please show your forms.py

Comment: check your `miapp\forms.py` line 19, change `validator` to `validators`. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators